# JTable установка фокуса на ячейку

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Есть jtable (10строк 2 столбца), необходимо установить фокус на ячейку (примерно на 5 строку 1 столбца)
Как сделать ?

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
<Tablename>.editCellAt(row,column);
```